# I keep getting JSONDecodeError when streaming this

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using Python requests library to stream a url and keep getting this error:

```
import json
import requests


s = requests.Session()
payload = {'limit': 0}
r = s.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker', params=payload, timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), stream=True)
r.raise_for_status()

for raw_rsvp in r.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
    if raw_rsvp:
        rsvp = json.loads(raw_rsvp)
        print(rsvp)
```

I understand that it is trying to read `json` before the object in the array is complete, how do I get around this?

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "benchmarks_generator.py", line 26, in refresh_coinmarketcap
    rsvp = json.loads(raw_rsvp)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: why am i getting downvoted, this question is legit not answered under [python-requests] tag search if you dont believe me

Comment: What does raw_rsvp contain?

Comment: @MrLeeh it has a '[' character in it, turns out the json object is not on one line but is preformatted from the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you're receiving `JSONDecodeError` because `b'['` and others are not valid `json` strings. And as long as the result is one array of JSON objects, you must obtain whole array to convert it to python obj.

So if you **must** use streaming request (`stream=True`), the only way is to read the output to a string buffer (or other kind of buffer to store temporary data) and when the transmission is finished, convert it to a JSON obj (this and other examples are written in `python3`):

```
import json
import requests

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'limit': 0}
r = s.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker', params=payload, stream=True)
r.raise_for_status()

buf = ''
for raw_rsvp in r.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
    buf += raw_rsvp.decode()  # bytes -> str for python3 compatibility

rsvp = json.loads(buf)
```

The other workaround is to catch every JSON obj from the stream and convert it to python obj, then put them one by one into a `list`. But it's a bit weird and **slow**:

```
import json
import requests

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'limit': 0}
r = s.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker', params=payload, stream=True)
r.raise_for_status()

buf = ''
rsvp = []
for raw_rsvp in r.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
    line = raw_rsvp.decode().strip()

    if line in ('[', ']'):
        pass
    elif line == '{':
        buf += line
    elif line in ('}', '},'):
        buf += line
        if buf.endswith(','):
            buf = buf[:-1]  # trim trailing comma
        rsvp.append(json.loads(buf))
        buf = ''  # erase buffer
    else:
        buf += line
```

P.S.: non-streaming request will be much easier:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
payload = {'limit': 0}
r = s.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker', params=payload)
r.raise_for_status()
rsvp = r.json()
```

Comment: thanks man!! will test these out, wish i could upvote more than once!